# Unexpected symbol in ddplot

Tags: r

I am typing this into R and it keeps telling me I have an unexpected symbol. Help!

```
  ddscale <- function(control, treatment){ n <- length(control)

control.scaled <- (control - mean(control[1:(n-1)])) /(sd(control[1:(n-1)])) treatment.hyp <- (control.scaled *(sd(treatment[1:(n-1)]) / sd(control.scaled[1:(n-1)])) +(mean(treatment[1:(n-1)]) - mean(control.scaled[1:(n-1)]))) treatment.hyp}
```

I've tried everything. Working on a mac

```
ddscale <- function(control, treatment){ n <- length(control)control.scaled <- (control - mean(control[1:(n-1)])) /(sd(control[1:(n-1)])) treatment.hyp <- (control.scaled *(sd(treatment[1:(n-1)]) / sd(control.scaled[1:(n-1)])) +(mean(treatment[1:(n-1)]) - mean(control.scaled[1:(n-1)]))) treatment.hyp}
```

Comment: Please improve your code  formatting(styling) for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

R commands must be separated by either a semi-colon (`;`) or a newline ([source](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#R-commands_002c-case-sensitivity_002c-etc_002e)). Your code contains multiple commands, all on the same line, without any command separators.

Here I have reformatted the first code snippet with additional line breaks and indentation for readability:

```
ddscale <- function(control, treatment) { 
  n <- length(control)
  control.scaled <- (control - mean(control[1:(n-1)])) / (sd(control[1:(n-1)]))
  treatment.hyp <- (control.scaled
    * (sd(treatment[1:(n-1)]) / sd(control.scaled[1:(n-1)]))
    + (mean(treatment[1:(n-1)]) - mean(control.scaled[1:(n-1)]))
  )
  treatment.hyp
}
```

This parses successfully using `Rscript`.